# Azure Permanently whitelisting IP

Tags: azure, ip, whitelist

Hope you are all safe!!!

I have a live project running on Azure Environment.

As part of data checking when i tried to access the Database using the SSMS in my machine, Everytime I need to white list my IP.

Since it is an intranet domain IP changes everyday.

Is there any solution to permanently enable my IP using mac address or something. So that i can jump over this IP Whitelisting.

Answer (score 0):

IP whitelisting (as the name already suggests), does not work on MAC address basis. What you could do as an alternative is to use a Point-to-Site VPN from your machine into an VNET in Azure. Then you should be able to leverage Private Endpoints (aka Private Link) to allow connections to your database from that VNET. https://samcogan.com/service-endpoints-and-private-link-whats-the-difference/